# Profinite groups are Galois groups

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, topological-groups, galois-extensions, profinite-groups

I tried to understand the proof on page 195 (in PDF page 17) [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwih6L3fzpbuAhXE-qQKHZDBCioQFjAGegQIDhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwwwen.uni.lu%2Fcontent%2Fdownload%2F75427%2F940970%2Ffile%2FRibes.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3r_vuvyIld73EJpo3zP_7R).

At the beginning $T$ is denoted as disjoint union of sets $G/U$.
Is it important for the proof that they are disjoint ?

After the definition of $G_{k}$ are some $t_{i}\in G/U_{i}$ taken, that appear in the rational expression of $k$. What does that mean?
Take they some $U_{i}$ so that $k$ mod $U_{i}$ equal $k$ or what is meant by that?
And why are there finally many $U_{i}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest relevant example is $$\Bbb{Z_p} =\varprojlim \Bbb{Z/p^kZ}$$

For each $k$ and $a\bmod p^k$ create a variable $T_{a\bmod p^k}$ and let $$K = \Bbb{Q}(\{ T_{a\bmod p^k},k\ge 1, a\in 0,\ldots p^k-1\})$$ which is a field of rational functions in infinitely many variables. Each $b\in \Bbb{Z}_p$ acts naturally as an automorphism $g_b\in Aut(K)$, switching the variables as $$g_b(T_{a\bmod p^k})=T_{a+b\bmod p^k}$$
It remains to look at $L$ the subfield fixed by $G=\{ g_b,b\in \Bbb{Z}_p\}\subset Aut(K)$ and find that $Gal(K/L)=G$ which is done in your linked text and cannot be made simpler in my opinion, the key argument being that for any $y\in K$ the Galois orbit  $G.y = \{g_b(y),b\in\Bbb{Z}_p\}$ is finite so that $L$ is generated over $\Bbb{Q}$ by the coefficients of the polynomials $$f_y(X)=\prod_{z\in G.y} (X-z) \in L[X]$$

Comment: Thank You
I think I understand the key argument but what is meant by $t_{i}$?
What conditions must every $t_{i}$ meet?

Comment: Please read my answer carefully, once it is clear with $\Bbb{Z}_p$ you won't have any problem to generalize to any profinite group.

Comment: Yes I don`t understand the explanation why $G.k$ is finite

Comment: No idea why I gave the same letter to $k$ and $k$, let me rename in the answer.

For some $n$ $$y\in \Bbb{Q}(\{ T_{a\bmod p^k},k\le n, a\in 0,\ldots p^k-1\})$$ $G$ gives only $p^n$ automorphisms of this field, so $G.y$ has at most $p^n$ elements.

Comment: Oh thank you. Why has an element of a field of rational functions with infinitely many 
variables finite many variables or did I misunderstood the argument ?

Comment: A rational function is a quotient of polynomials. The polynomial ring has infinitely many variables but each polynomial depends only on finitely of them.